# If a chicken crosses the road, is it still a pedestrian?

Tags: meaning, nouns, word-usage

A *pedestrian* is *one who travels on foot*, *ped* being the Latin root for foot. But even though many people refer to chicken's feet as *feet*, are they actually *feet* scientifically speaking, such that they would qualify as being *pedestrian* when walking on them? What about animals with hooves, or paws?

Note: This is a question about the meaning of the English word *pedestrian*, specifically how (and if) it applies to non-humans.

Comment: What has this to do with English?

Comment: This is a question about the meaning of the English word `pedestrian`, specifically how (and if) it applies to non-humans.

Comment: Yes, chicken feet are actually feet.

Comment: The African Bush Elephant or the Polar Bear..would still be pedestrians, if they intend to share the sidewalk with us.+1

Comment: If someone told me they'd just seen a *pedestrian chicken* (whether crossing the road or not) I'd probably assume they meant it was a [*dull, plodding, boring, tedious, monotonous, uneventful, unremarkable, tiresome, wearisome, uninspired, uncreative, unimaginative, unexciting, uninteresting, lifeless, dry*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/pedestrian) chicken.

Comment: If after crossing the road on foot (or claw), the chicken perches on the branch of a tree, it ceases to be a pedestrian and instead becomes a rooster.

Comment: If a pony can be a bird, then surely a chicken can be a pedestrian; see [_Regina v. Ojibway_](https://media.law.wisc.edu/s/c_420/ytvkn/gargoyle_12_4_7.pdf).

Comment: I'd say that's a rather pedestrian question.

Answer (score 4):

In case of animals I think  the correct terms are: [biped](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/biped):

> - an animal with two feet.

or  [quadriped](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quadriped):

> - a four-footed animal.

a [pedestrian](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pedestrian) is a human being.

(from TFD)

Comment: Not forgetting 'milliped' for millipedes, and 'centiped' for centipedes. :)

Comment: And _pseudoped_ for amoebas.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use *pedestrian* for animals and it has nothing to do with its origin. (for the same sense as a human pedestrian). Though, you have to mention "animal" or the name of the animal along with "pedestrian", otherwise "pedestrian" itself would be understood as a human pedestrian by default.

Examples:

> Keeping the Streets Safe for **Animal Pedestrians**
>
> <sub>http://www.cityofrc.us/cityhall/animalcare/field/wildlife/safe_streets.asp</sub>
>
> ---
>
> It seemed that in the rural highlands of Scotland, cars certainly had the right-of-way over pedestrians, and **animal pedestrians** at that!
>
> <sub>The Countess of Erroll *By Ed. D Edwards, S. Elizabeth Edwards*</sub>

---

There is also the usage of *pedestrian* in biology to define animals that walk on foot.

> These rules refer, of course, to **pedestrian animals**, not flying animals or climbing animals. **The human animal is a pedestrian**, although he is descended from arboreal primates and has some climbing ability.
>
> <sub>The Ecological Approach To Visual Perception *By James J. Gibson* [2013]</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Studying the locomotion of **aquatic pedestrian animals** will contribute  to our ideas about possible constraints on a amphibious lifestyle, and the evolutionary transition between aquatic and terrestrial environments.
>
> <sub>Issues for Aquatic Pedestrian Locomotion - *Marlene M. Martinez* [1996] 
>
>   http://icb.oxfordjournals.org/content/36/6/619.full.pdf</sub>

Comment: "If you do hit an animal, attempt to help to the best of your abilities,...but do not handle the animal because of a rabies risk."   
  
So we use Jedi mind control?

Comment: @CarSmack: Well, it is not related to topic but there are signs of rabies.

Comment: @ermanen - Forget about rabies, what about ebola??

Comment: @HotLicks - What about love?

Answer (score 0):

Almost every definition I've found online refers to "a person" travelling on foot, or similar, for example:

[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pedestrian) says "*a person who goes or travels on foot; walker.*";

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedestrian) says "*a person who is walking in a city, along a road, etc.*";

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pedestrian) says "*a person who is walking, especially in an area where vehicles go*".

An exception is [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pedestrian), which says "*Somebody walking rather than using a vehicle; somebody travelling on foot on or near a roadway.*"  However, they also define "*somebody*" as "*Some unspecified person.*".

So it appears that only humans may be pedestrian. There doesn't appear to be an equivalent word for those equipped with hooves or paws - perhaps *ungulaetrian* and *cruratrian*, if one were in a silly mood.

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone deemed this answer so unhelpful that it deserved to be downvoted, but two people did (without comment). My upvote is an attempt to rebalance the scales a bit. You might strengthen your answer somewhat by quoting and linking to one or two of the definitions of _pedestrian_ you've found online that refer specifically and exclusively to "a person"; one candidate might be [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedestrian), whose only definition of _pedestrian_ as a noun is "a person who is walking in a city, along a road, etc."

Comment: As ermanen has found references to animal pedestrians, perhaps the dictionaries should be updated, rather than my answer downvoted?  I'm not too bothered though.